# How to pass the creation month of a Wordpress post to a custom variable in Google Analytics

Tags: wordpress, analytics

I'm trying to register the month of publishing of my Wordpress posts as a Page-level custom variable in GA, but I don't know how to:

1. Get the "month" variable in Wordpress
2. Put the code on the header of single posts only (no landing pages or "about" pages, p. ex.)

For example, if a post was created in december, i would like to pass the variable "Month", with the value "12" to GA.

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can get the month variable by doing `<?php the_date('m'); ?>`. Just put that whereever you need it within the individual page or post template and it should pass the numerical value of the month.